# How to check a token in authentication

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, authentication

I am trying to make my first authentication with MERN and I faced a problem. I have a form, on submit it checks inputs' values and if it's alright it should open the main page. I can see in console that everything works and I see a token in cookies, but I still can't open the main page.
I can see that the problem is in useToken.js, but I completely stuck into it because I can't change localStorage to cookies.
(The project is very basic and I don't need any validations, I just need to see other components when logged in)
Thank you very much for any help.
GitHub repository if needed.
https://github.com/daryalewy/kickstarter-app

Auth.js

```
import useToken from "../Components/useToken";


export default function Auth() {
  const Body = styled.section`
    min-height: 550px;
    min-width: 319.98px;
    background: linear-gradient(
      0deg,
      rgba(213, 189, 238, 1) 0%,
      rgba(166, 124, 232, 1) 100%
    );
    padding-top: 40px;
    position: relative;
  `;

  const { token, setToken } = useToken();

  if (!token) {
    return (
      <>
        <Body>
          <Logo />
          <Login setToken={setToken} />
        </Body>
        <Socials />
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/">
            <MainPage />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
```

useToken.js

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function useToken() {
  const getToken = () => {
    const tokenString = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const userToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);
    return userToken?.token
  };

  const [token, setToken] = useState(getToken());

  const saveToken = userToken => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(userToken));
    setToken(userToken.token);
  };

  return {
    setToken: saveToken,
    token
  }
}
```

Routes in backend

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!isEmail(email)) {
      throw new Error('Email must be a valid email address.');
    }
    if (typeof password !== 'string') {
      throw new Error('Password must be a string.');
    }
    const user = new User({ email, password });
    const persistedUser = await user.save();
    const userId = persistedUser._id;

    const session = await initSession(userId);

    res
      .cookie('token', session.token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: true,
        maxAge: 1209600000,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      })
      .status(201)
      .json({
        title: 'User Registration Successful',
        detail: 'Successfully registered new user',
        csrfToken: session.csrfToken,
      });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
      errors: [
        {
          title: 'Registration Error',
          detail: 'Something went wrong during registration process.',
          errorMessage: err.message,
        },
      ],
    });
  }
});

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!isEmail(email)) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        errors: [
          {
            title: 'Bad Request',
            detail: 'Email must be a valid email address',
          },
        ],
      });
    }
    if (typeof password !== 'string') {
      return res.status(400).json({
        errors: [
          {
            title: 'Bad Request',
            detail: 'Password must be a string',
          },
        ],
      });
    }
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error();
    }
    const userId = user._id;

    const passwordValidated = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!passwordValidated) {
      throw new Error();
    }

    const session = await initSession(userId);

    res
      .cookie('token', session.token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: true,
        maxAge: 1209600000,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      })
      .json({
        title: 'Login Successful',
        detail: 'Successfully validated user credentials',
        csrfToken: session.csrfToken,
      });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).json({
      errors: [
        {
          title: 'Invalid Credentials',
          detail: 'Check email and password combination',
          errorMessage: err.message,
        },
      ],
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not between cookie or local-storage. It is you never actually set token!

In your `Login.js`, you should call `props.setToken(res)` inside

```
axios
  .post("/api/users/login", user)
  .then((res) => {
     //Call it here
}
```

Also you need to make sure Login component has its props passed in:

```
export default function Login(props) {
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I still don't get it to be honest, I tried this way but I got nothing. Can you please explain it? What props exactly should I pass? I tried to pass token, but it doesn't work. I really can't get it because im just learning and it's hard for me, so i would really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance

Comment: In your `Auth.js` you wrote `<Login setToken={setToken} />` means you pass `setToken` as props to Login component. But in Login component you didn't actually use `setToken`. From my understanding I thought you may want to setToken after you get result of your axios post.(snippet 1) And to use setToken you need to anounce props first. (snippet 2)